Getting wix contact list from backend function
I am using wix to build a website for an external application that I am building, and I am trying to link them together using wix's backend functions. I need to be able to access my wix contact list using python, so I am trying to create an http endpoint that will give me access to this list using a python request.
I am trying to use the elevate function to bypass the permissions, because before I was only getting FORBIDDEN error messages when calling my function. Using elevate has stopped the FORBIDDEN errors, but now all items that are being returned are null. When I do results.length, it returns 11 (which is the proper amount of contacts currently in my list) but the 11 items that are being returned are null. I do not understand why the function is able to count the number of contacts but unable to return the data of the contacts themselves.
Here is the code for my backend function. When calling test2 in python, the status code is 200 but returns an empty list because all items are null. How can I see the values of the items themselves?
